# Flows with flow bulkification to check if record exists

Tags: visual-workflow, bulkification

I am creating a flow which can be invoked in bulk mode with multiple records.  I have read the help articles for automatic flow bulkification, and have a good idea what's going on.

I have a requirement that a certain action only proceeds if a record (which is a different record from the one being updated, but which looks at one of the fields on the record being updated) exists.

With just one record, I would simply do a GetRecords to see if the record exists, and then add a 'is not null' decision.  But will this bulkify correctly, or is there a better way to make sure that bulkification works?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It's a very legit question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principle is fairly simple -- in a transaction of 2+ records that enter the flow, separate Flow Interviews are created. These run effectively in "parallel" [until they reach a bulkifiable element](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_bulkification.htm&type=5). In your case, that is the Get Records element

- SFDC constructs a *single* filter for a bulkified Get Record using the inputs from each Flow Interview. This might be a collection of Ids or strings or dates
- SFDC executes the SOQL query once and distributes the results back to the individual Flow Interviews.
- To the Flow Developer, you worry only about a single Flow Interview and let SFDC handle the magic of bulkification for you

Example

- Interview 1 - Get Record to see if `MyObj__c.My_Field__c` with value `aa` exists
- Interview 2 - Get Record `MyObj__c.My_Field__c` with value `bb` exists
- SFDC bulkifies the Get Records and does an implicit `IN ('aa','bb')` for the SOQL

If only `aa` exists, SFDC returns a Record to Interview 1 and returns NULL to Interview 2.

**Notes**

1. One Flow Interview can't know what is going on in a separate Flow Interview. If this is important, you need to use Apex Actions.
2. One Flow Interview can't rely on updates done in a separate Flow Interview in the same transaction
3. Don't forget to avoid `Get/Create/Update/Delete Record` elements in loops as those can blow up Limits. Winter 23 gives us the `IN` operator (finally) in Get Records so you can provide a collection variable to use in the query (just like SOQL  `... IN (someObjectList)` )

Comment: The flow author needs to avoid "record" elements in loops still.

Comment: Rather surprisingly, that actually worked!

Comment: can you elaborate the 3 point (Dont forget to avoid....)

Comment: @user533 - elaborated on my answer

Comment: thanjs @cropredy